# XLSX writer implementation

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, excel

We have multiple scripts which write into XLSX with the same format, into a different format or slide variation. I am trying to write an API which saves time for other programs, but I need input on restructuring the file.

```
import openpyxl
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

class xlsx_extend(object):
    """This class contain api of xlsx functionality"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        """create xls file"""
        self.xlsx_name = Workbook(name)
        self.create_format('blue', 12)

    def create_format(self, color, size):
        """write header"""
        self.xlsx_format = self.xlsx_name.add_format()
        self.xlsx_format.set_font_size(size)
        self.xlsx_format.set_bold()
        self.xlsx_format.set_color(color)
        self.xlsx_format.set_border()
        self.xlsx_format.set_center_across()
        self.xlsx_format.set_align('center')
        self.xlsx_format.set_rotation(90)

    def add_sheet(self, ws_name):
        """Adding worksheet name"""
        return self.xlsx_name.add_worksheet(ws_name)

    def rotate_text_format(self, angle):
        """rotate the text data"""
        self.xlsx_format.set_rotation(angle)

    def get_xlsx_name(self):
        """Returing xlsx name for derive class"""
        return self.xlsx_name

    def close_xlsx(self):
        """close xlsx File"""
        self.xlsx_name.close()

class xlsx_sheet:
    """This is xlsx worksheet class"""
    def __init__(self, excel_sheet, ws_name):
        """Initialze Base function and Create Worksheet"""
        self.excel_sheet = excel_sheet
        self.ws_name_worksheet = excel_sheet.add_sheet(ws_name)
        self.ws_name_worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 40)

    def write(self, row, col, data, format=None):
        """write Add in xlsx File"""
        self.ws_name_worksheet.write(row, col, data)

    def write_column(self, row, col, data, format=None):
        """write data in column than need pass data as list"""
        self.ws_name_worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

    def write_row(self, row, col, data, format=None):
        """write data in row than need to pass as list"""
        self.ws_name_worksheet.write_row(row, col, data, self.excel_sheet.xlsx_format)

    def write_comment(self, row, col, data):
        """write comment in cell"""
        self.ws_name_worksheet.write_comment(row, col, data, {'width': 400, 'height': 400})

    def text_condition_format(self, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col, value, format):
        """Adding text condition format"""
        self.ws_name_worksheet.conditional_format(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col,
            {'type': 'text',
            'criteria': 'containing',
            'value': value,
            'format': format
            })
```

And another module with it's call API like:

```
report_xlsx = xlsxutils.xlsx_extend("report.xlsx")
red_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color': '#FF0000'})
green_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color':'#99CC32'})
gray_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color':'#53868B'})
blue_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color':'#3298FE'})
light_red_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color':'#FF9999'})

report_worksheet = xlsxutils.xlsx_sheet(report_xlsx, "Report") 

report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'P', green_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'F', red_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'AB', red_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'RU', light_red_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'QU', light_red_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'M', gray_format)
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'UN', blue_format)
report_xlsx.close_xlsx()
```

Can you do code review and provide your input?

Answer (score 3):

### Naming Conventions

According to the official Python style guide, class names should be in `PascalCase`:

```
No:
    class my_class():
Yes:
    class MyClass():
```

In your case, I would capitalize the entire `xlsx` because it is an acroynm:

```
class XSLXExtend():
```

---

There also seems to be some redundancy in some of your names:

```
# worksheet_name_worksheet?
self.ws_name_worksheet
```

---

This next point may be speaking on an intentional design measure, but I would take a look at what properties are supposed to be 'public' and which are meant to be 'private'. Even though Python [doens't truly have private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641219/does-python-have-private-variables-in-classes), it is still convention to use a single underscore ('_') at the start of any intended private variables.

```
self._i_should_be_private = 'No touching!'
```

---

Some of your names are misleading:

```
# Wait. This stores the actual Workbook not its name?
self.xlsx_name = Workbook(name)
```

### Structure

I am not a big fan of declaring instance variables outside of the `__init__` method. In lieu of this, I would refactor your `create_format()` method as such:

```
def create_format(self, color, size):
    format = self.xlsx_name.addFormat()
    format.set_font_size(size)
    format.set_bold()
    format.set_color(color)
    format.set_border()
    format.set_center_across()
    format.set_align('center')
    format.set_rotation(90)

    return format
```

Then just put this line in the `__init__` method: `self.format = create_format('blue', 12)`.

---

Also, you have an accessor method (which is nice) for `xlsx_name`. However, in your code that actually uses your classes, you just directly access it:

```
# Why even have `get_xlsx_name()` if you don't use it?
red_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format(...)
```

The same goes for your `create_format()` method. You use it once in `__init__` but don't when you **actually use** your class. You skip straight to the `Workbook`:

```
red_format = report_xlsx.xlsx_name.add_format({'bg_color': '#FF0000'})
```

Essentially you are circumventing all the work you did wrapping the `Workbook` class in another class.

---

Since your `xlsx_extend` class is supposed to store data about and manipulate a `Workbook` why not store all of the formats there? Here is what I would do:

```
class XLSXExtension(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.xlsx_name = Workbook(name)
        self.formats = {}

        self.create_format('blue', 'blue')

    def create_format(self, name, color, size=12):
        format = self.xlsx_name.addFormat()
        format.set_font_size(size)
        format.set_bold()
        format.set_color(color)
        format.set_border()
        format.set_center_across()
        format.set_align('center')
        format.set_rotation(90)

        self.formats[name] = format

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.formats[key]
        except KeyError:
            print('Format "{}" not found.'.format(key))


report_xlsx = xlsxutils.xlsx_extend("report.xlsx")
report_xlsx.create_format('red', '#FF0000')
report_xlsx.create_format('green', '#99CC32', 24)

report_worksheet = xlsxutils.xlsx_sheet(report_xlsx, "Report") 
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'P', report_xlsx['green'])
report_worksheet.text_condition_format(1, 1, row, col, 'F', report_xlsx['red'])
```